# Finding all the POIs in the world using OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, point-of-interest

I would like to extract airports' boundaries from OpenStreetMap.
Therefore, to extract data from a given country, for instance France I do:

```
area["name"="France"]->.boundaryarea;
(
node(area.boundaryarea)["aeroway"="aerodrome"];
way(area.boundaryarea)["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>;
relation(area.boundaryarea)["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>>;
);
out meta;
```

However, I would like to search for such data for the whole world, i.e. without limiting the area.
Is there a node representing the world or do I have to loop such queries country by country ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can just drop the area parts of your query to get what you want:

```
 (
 node["aeroway"="aerodrome"];
 way["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>;
 relation["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>>;);
 out meta;
```

but your query might get cancelled due to server load.

Alternatively, you can query by bbox fo parts of the world.

Comment: Union is missing in the answer, otherwise nodes, ways and relations will never be in the query result. It should read: `(node["aeroway"="aerodrome"];
 way["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>;
 relation["aeroway"="aerodrome"];>>;);out meta;`. Also, `[maxsize: ]` and `[timeout: ]` are most likely needed as well. In any case, I would start with smaller bboxes rather than a global query.

Comment: And, of course, you could dl the data yourself and work w/ that (it's huge, but somewhat useful to have locally).